# Help! Large gaping on newly installed solid bamboo floors

Tags: flooring, gap

Im in a dilemma with flooring.

We had our old laminate flooring removed and replaced with solid strand woven click lock bamboo. We used what we though was a reputable company, they had insurance, good reviews on yelp, etc etc.

Installation was completed 11/16(Saturday). The next week, we saw gaps in certain areas- hallway. I contacted the company I was working with and they gave me the whole "wood expands/ contracts/ maybe heat issues" talk. I explained that I understood and that there was always air circulation in our apartment and that I didn't believe it was due to temperature SO fast after the installation. Mind you, the wood had acclimated after delivery in our home for at least a week.

They came back exactly a week after, on 11/23 to repair the hallway gap.

[image]

^Hallway 11/22/19 After Installation completed on 11/16 and gaps showed^

Just days after the repair, the same gaps appeared in the. EXACT same place! It also got bigger.

I believe the company did not properly interlock the wood pieces.

Any advice? The company is not nudging from saying its a 'heat/ expansion" issue, but its highlight suspicious to me that the gaps happened so fast and in the same area.

[image]

^ Hallway on 11/30 after the repair^ gaps are very big- measured over 1cm.

They also never repaired the gap in one of the bedrooms, which has now gotten worse. I am being polite and trying to get them to come back and acknowledge that this was an installation issue.

Thoughts? Is this shoddy installation? Or am I crazy?

What steps can I take? I already contacted our insurance but this wont be covered because its would be a "workmanship" issue. I may need to have another company/ some else else look out it but thats $$$ on top of everything spent.

Thank you!

Comment: The offending area appears to be at a minor junction and next to a bathroom, laundry, or kitchen with green tile. Is there water, moisture, or temp changes nearby?

Comment: How did they "repair" the gap? Bang the planks together again, or pull out and re-install? Is this a floating floor, or nailed/glued to the subfloor?

Comment: How long was the flooring material sitting in your home before it was installed (preferably unwrapped)?

Comment: That one corner looks so tight the floor will never contract/expand..... definitely looks like an installation problem.

Comment: OMG thank you everyone! This is SO helpful in battling with the contractor.                     @bishop yes its next to a bathroom but never had any leakage or water or anything there. No heaters or windows nearby.

Comment: @ spuck- they removed the quarter round molding, pulled out all the wood and re-installed. This is a floating wood floor

Comment: @JPhi1618- The wood acclimated for at least 7 days at our home.Unfortunately it was not unwrapped- we had 62 boxes and I asked if they had to be unwrapped and was told no :(

Comment: @JACK- I will point that out to them, thank you!